# Passing property to custom gradle task from command prompt

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I wrote a custom gradle task class (say `PrintNameTask`) that accepts some input parameter (say `name`).

Then if I define a `printName` task of type `PrintNameTask` like below:

```
task printName(type: PrintNameTask) {
    name = project.name
}
```

and invoke it from command prompt like below I can see the passed name printed out

```
$gradle printName -Pname=myName
myName
```

However if I invoke any other task like `clean` or `build` the build fails because there is no property called `name` passed. This is fair enough as my `printName` is a configure closure and is evaluated all the times.

To address this I tried to change the configure closure into a task action closure like below:

```
task printName(type: PrintNameTask) << {
    // What should I put on here?
    name = ???
    // or
    name ???
}
```

But it was no way to make it work. I tried project.name, getProperty("name") and a few more other combinations but nothing worked. All I get back is:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':printName'.
No value has been specified for property 'name'.
```

This kind of requirement looks to me quite basic and it is a bit frustrating that tons of books and documentation are published but they only shows trivial examples. Maybe is just me but at the point of asking this question my initial gradle enthusiasm is more than half gone. Anyway thank you in advance for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the task in the following way:

```
task printName(type: PrintNameTask) {
    name = project.hasProperty('name') ? project.name : '' // or null
}
```

Since this closure is evaluated at configuration phase it's executed every time the script is processed. You just need to check if the property is present.

Comment: Thanks Opal. It worked. But to me it looks like a work around. It would be good to find out how you will pass a property from command prompt to a execution closure (TaskAction) so it will only be evaluated when you specifially execute that task. If I don't need to execute a task why should I be required to to pass (or to default if for this matter) a property that will only make sense in certain scenarios. Say properties required when running a `deploy` task should not be needed when running a `jar` task. With your approach  I will configure the `deploy` even if no need for it at all.

Comment: That's not a workaround. This is how gradle works. If I helped you, please accept. When you run particular task the *whole* script is evaluated. That's why you need the logic I provided.

Comment: Well if this is how gradle works then in my view gradle should be improved. To be forced to configure something I know upfront I don’t need looks a design gap to me.
Anyway your answer helped me solve my problem and move further so it is fair to accepting it as a solution. Once again thank you very much.